# How do I embed a list from another SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, list, task-list

I am attempting to embed list content into a SharePoint page that is stored on a separate SP within our enterprise. The goal is to create a centralized dashboard for reps to see various dynamic tasks that need to be completed (assigned to the group) and are currently on several different SPs.  I am building a page to pull the content from the lists stored on these various SPs; that way all the tasks will display on one page, instead of reps having to visit 5 different SPs.

I have found a few potential solutions that make it sound really simple to do this, but they assume you’re pulling from subsites, or to a subsite and encourage using Content Query or Data View Webparts.

I’ve currently pulled the pages from the SPs and embedded using the Page Viewer WebPart as a work around for now, but that’s far from ideal.

What’s the best method of accomplishing this?  Help me Obi-wan Kenobi . . .

Answer (score 0):

As I you are using the SharePoint 2013 version, in this version Microsoft has introduced a beautiful feature for this kind of requirement i.e **content search** web part. This works on the search level meaning the data source could be  of sites but finally after crawling this will be a single data source that is **search result**.

So, in order to customize the search result you need to know how **display template** works in SharePoint. For any type of content search web part, there will be two templates **header** and **item display template**. You need to customize these two templates, here you will get all sort of flexibility and it pure javascripting and REST API code, so we can make the colorful beautiful dashboard.

Another advantage of customizing the content search web part is, it handles permissions automatically as it works on the item search, so no need to put extra effort for permission in the source items.

So, considering the above advantages and flexibility of content search web part, this will be a recommended approach.